# How to obtain Fritz Perls' Eye Witness to Therapy film?

Tags: reference-request, psychiatry

I am reading Fritz Perls' book called "Eye Witness to Therapy" which contains film transcipts that Perls thought would be useful to learn Gestalt therapy.

For me it is a very deep and interesting reading, but I'm wondering whether seeing the actual films would benefit me.

I was searching around but I couldn't find any reference on how to get those films. If anyone could help that would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: would you post some transcript content?

Comment: I found three films there: http://www.auditorium-netzwerk.de/Fachbereiche/Psychologie-und-Psychotherapie/Gestalttherapie/Fritz-Perls-Gestalt-in-Aktion:::5_5312_5318_5476.html Don't know whether they are worth the money, though.

Answer (score 3):

[This youtube channel has videos labeled "Fritz Perl ClipN"](http://www.youtube.com/user/paulchabe?feature=watch) where N = 1,2,3, 4.0 and 5:

- [Clip1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ps6PHYBUnuk&feature=plcp)
- [Clip2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlayqPwDuz0&feature=plcp)
- [Clip3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkiK9vo3C_k&feature=plcp)
- [Clip4](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8P4-qhWSUk0&feature=plcp)
- [Clip5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2o9vdXN4490&feature=plcp)

Comment: could you comment on the poster's question of "I'm wondering whether seeing the actual films would benefit me"? Is this film worth seeing to understand Gestalt therapy or are there better sources?

Comment: no, I've never read/watched Perl.  I was just lending my search skills.